# Real Time Timer stops after using world_control message

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[C:\fakepath\img.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/15433019688375039.png) I am using ~/world_control for controlling simulation using multi_sim_step.
I used world_msg.set_multi_step(1000) to set sim time. As soon as I set this, SimTime is updating but RealTime don't change in Gazebo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21207/real-time-timer-stops-after-using-world_control-message/) by [Gaurav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6898/gaurav/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I realize this can be confusing, but the real time indicator shows the wall time elapsed while the simulation was **playing**. However, when you're stepping the simulation, it is technically **paused** (note how you can see the play button). That's why real time is not elapsing and the real time factor is zero.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gaurav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6898/gaurav/) on 2018-11-30**:
Thanks. Is there any way to step simulation without affecting real time factor and real time using transport api? or we can't do this while Gazebo stepping?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-12-01**:
I think you should be able to keep track of wall time inside your program/plugin that's doing the stepping.

**Comment by [Gaurav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6898/gaurav/) on 2018-12-03**:
Sure. Thanks.